# Reference for couple facts in algebraic topology (tautological line bundle, principle G bundle)

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I have seen the following couple of (basic and possible obvious) facts written when I look up sources on the internet, but I'm not so sure why they are true or where to find them.

1) We mentioned Brown representability in class and the application to showing the existence of classifying spaces $B$ and universal printipal $G$-bundles $P\rightarrow B$. As an easy consequence, $B$ is unique up to homotopy. I have read that $P$ is unique up to $G$-homotopy (homotopy that commutes with the action of $G$), but I'm not sure how one might prove it.

Is it also obvious, or could somebody sketch or point to a reference?

2) What is a direct way to show that the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{L}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ is universal (without passing through $U(1)$-bundles)? I'm having trouble even finding a statement of this fact, but this might be just because many of the hits when I google this come from algebraic geometry.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your second question, but I believe it's shown in Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*.

Comment: Do you know about what chapter I might be looking for (and I'll check it out of the library)?

Comment: Perhaps Theorem 14.6.  It refers back to Theorem 5.6 (the real case).  I'm not sure if this is quite the statement you're looking for, but it might be helpful.

Comment: For the second question I also immediately had to think about the book by Milnor and Stasheff mentioned. The first question I expect to be answered in D. Husemoller's "Fiber bundles".

Comment: Yes, Theorem 5.6 in Milnor's characteristic classes seems to say what I'm looking for, as I didn't know how we got a bundle map into the tautological bundle from an arbitrary bundle.

I'll go look at the Fiber Bundles book when I get a chance, thanks.